# why does System.Numerics.Vector3.Transform gets a Matrix4x4 by copy and not reference?

Tags: c#, optimization, matrix

I am developing a graphic application that needs to perform a lot of vector transformations.

I use `System.Numerics.Vector3` as vectors and `System.Numerics.Matrix4x4` as matrices. Both of them are structures, so when try to transform many different vectors with the same matrix, my application becomes really slow because of `System.Numerics.Vector3.Transform()` passes matrix by value.

Is there a reason for this? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Its a side-effect of value types, the only way to fix it is to roll your own classes, you can't change value types to pass by reference without using the ref keyword in the method definition. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b0bdca4.aspx

Comment: The problem is that `Transform` does not accept reference as a valid parameter. Is creating my own classes (and thus duplicating code, and losing great features such as SIMD) the only solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to change the System.Numerics system to use reference passing. Maybe you can run your benchmarks on another system like Math.Net (http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) to see if SIMD is really giving you as much of a benefit as you hope.